# Prefixr for Webstorm? Cross-browser CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there any way to integrate prefixr into webstorm? Or rather is there a way to make cross-browser CSS using webstorm/phpstorm.

There is an add on for sublime text, so I was hoping that there would be something similar here.

Comment: Prefixr support ticket: [WEB-37](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37)  (currently not planned for any specific version). Regarding *"is there a way to make cross-browser CSS..."* -- I suggest checking out [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and **[Compass](http://compass-style.org/)**